# Cache property read from database

Tags: kotlin

Currently I'm starting to learn Kotlin. I have a property like this:

```
var startTime: Int
    get() = {
        // read value from database
    }
    set(value) {
        // save value to database
    }
```

Here I always read and write the value every time I use the getter and setter.

Can this property be evaluated lazy? I want to read the value once the first time I use the getter and cache it for following calls. I know that values can be lazy but I found nothing about variables. What is the correct way in Kotlin to cache this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is not lazy evaluation, but a backing field:

```
private var _startTime: Int? = null

var startTime: Int
    get() = {
        if (_startTime != null) {
            return _startTime!!
        } else {
            // read value from database and assign it to _startTime
        } 
    }
    set(value) {
        _startTime = value 
        // save value to database
    }
```

Alternatively you could declare `_startTime` as non-nullable and have an additional flag `private var isStartTimeSet: Boolean = false` used for checking if it has been fetched from database already.

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin offers lazy properties (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy) that are computed on first access and cached.

```
val lazyValue: String by lazy {
  println("computed!")
  "Hello"
}
```

​

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println(lazyValue)
  println(lazyValue)
}
```

Will produce

```
computed!
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: Yeah I know that but I need this for a variable (which has get and set) and not a value which is only readable.

Comment: @Cilenco I don't get it ... why would you cache a value that you can change? How will you know when to get a new value from the database?

Comment: The value can only be changed by my program. In some cases I have to query the value very often which results in bad performance when doing it all the time from the DB. Sometimes I don't even have to get the value so lazy loading would be good here.

Comment: Just change it to a var...?